# 403 (ModSecurity Action) for a blazor server-side web app

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

In my **asp.net core 3.1 blazor server-side web app**, i get this **403 ModSecurity** errors for the **inbuilt blazor's /_blazor/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1 request**.

[image]

From the server log from the hosting provider, I got these logs stating that my **C# code** needs to be modified in order to fix these errors:

```
  [id  "**960009**"] [rev "1"] **[msg "Request Missing a User Agent Header"]** 
               [severity "NOTICE"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/2.2.9"] [maturity "9"] 
               [accuracy "9"] [tag 
               "OWASP_CRS/PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/MISSING_HEADER_UA"] [tag 
               "WASCTC/WASC-21"] [tag "OWASP_TOP_10/A7"] [tag "PCI/6.5.10"] 
               [hostname "xxxx"] [uri "/"]

[id "**960010**"] [rev "2"] **[msg "Request content type 
               is not allowed by policy"] [data "text/plain"]** [severity 
               "CRITICAL"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/2.2.9"] [maturity "9"] [accuracy 
               "9"] [tag "OWASP_CRS/POLICY/ENCODING_NOT_ALLOWED"] [tag 
               "WASCTC/WASC-20"] [tag "OWASP_TOP_10/A1"] [tag 
               "OWASP_AppSensor/EE2"] [tag "PCI/12.1"] [hostname 
               "xxxx"] [uri "/_blazor/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1"]
```

I have been told by the hosting partner that these could be fixed on the code side, in the startup configuration, is there anything that I could do to fix the **User-agent and content type headers** for the inbuilt **/_blazor/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1** request?

Answer (score 0):

See these error messages:

1. *Request Missing a User Agent Header*
   Simply add correct User-Agent header.
2. *Request content type is not allowed by policy*
   Looks like your hosting provider is no allowing text/plain as value for Content-Type header, which is weired. Try contacting him.